# How do i make the pop-up from the form appear behind the background-blur?

Tags: html, css, forms, modal-dialog

I made an alert pop-up that appears when the user input in the form is not valid.
I set the z index of the background blur to 10000 (highest in the whole program) but that automatic pop-up from the form "please include an '@' in the email address." is still above it.
Is there a way to fix it?

[image]

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <p id="modal-content"></p>
        <button onclick="closeModal()">OK</button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-background" id="modalBackground"></div>
```

```
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 100000;
}

.modal-background {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 10000;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the validation where you check, I would try removing the focus on the input, or possibly modifying the default validation bubble in CSS.

```
/* The entire area of the popup including area outside the bubble shape */
 ::-webkit-validation-bubble{}
/* Portion above the bubble behind top arrow */
 ::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow-clipper{}
/* The arrow at the top of the bubble */
 ::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow{}
/* The area containing the validation message */
 ::-webkit-validation-bubble-message{}
```